# How to properly test a MCU network interface

Tags: ethernet

I created a board based on an MCU, this MCU has a network interface that I connected to a PHY and an RJ45 connector.
This interface is only for future developments, I don't currently need it, but to validate the board and start production I need to know if the hardware (the board) is well made and working or not.

For now I simply made a small firmware that responds to ping, and if I try to ping my board from a PC everything seems to be ok.

Now the question is: is it enough the ping test to be able to say that all the hardware related to the network interface of my board is working correctly?
Or are other tests needed, for example I need to experiment by writing a TCP server or something like that?

Comment: Which MCU it uses and how did you make the Ethernet hardware?

Comment: @Justme MCU: STM32H745IIT6 and PHY: LAN8742AI-CZ

Answer (score 1):

What the ping tests is that the hardware works up to the point to be able to send and receive packets. It basically proves it can functionally work, at least with small packets that are sent rarely. The defaul ping settings do not use large packets but you can likely tune the settings tonsend larger packets more often.

It does not mean the Ethernet interface is properly made, good, or will fulfill Ethernet electrical interface requiremets, or if the device will pass any required safety, EMC, EMI, and ESD testing.

So it may have signal integrity issues, or the hardware may fail to work under heavy traffic, not because Ethernet PHY but the MCU.

There are many network testing programs that could be used to validate the Ethernet interface, both functionally and electrically, so even a simple program that communicates over TCP or UDP could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/689595/101063) from Justme contains:

> The default ping settings do not use large packets but you can likely tune the settings to send larger packets more often.

I agree it is a good test to get ping to send larger packets as can sometimes find issues in the MCU network stack software. E.g. for a [MSP432E401Y](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP432E401Y) using the manufactures MCU network stack found [MSP432E401Y: NDK in simplelink_msp432e4_sdk_4_20_00_12 can't send fragmented UDP packets, but can receive them](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp-low-power-microcontrollers-group/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/938134/msp432e401y-ndk-in-simplelink_msp432e4_sdk_4_20_00_12-can-t-send-fragmented-udp-packets-but-can-receive-them):

1. With a ping size of the maximum for one Ethernet frame then successful:

   ```
   $ ping 192.168.0.5 -s 1474
   PING 192.168.0.5 (192.168.0.5) 1474(1502) bytes of data.
   1482 bytes from 192.168.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.703 ms
   ```
2. Whereas increasing the ping size by one byte then failed:

   ```
   $ ping 192.168.0.5 -s 1475
   PING 192.168.0.5 (192.168.0.5) 1475(1503) bytes of data.
   1483 bytes from 192.168.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.736 ms
   wrong data byte #1474 should be 0xc2 but was 0x7d
   ```

   This caused the ICMP payload to be split into two Ethernet frames, and Wireshark reports the transmitted ICMP checksum is invalid.

Even if the network interface is for future use, it may be worth *stress testing* it now with maximum size Ethernet frames and maximum data rates to find any reliability issues before you need to use the network interface. If get some failures then need to determine if either.

- The failure is caused in your hardware.
- The MCU network stack software, which might need to be reported to the manufacturer

Comment: If just using ping, in addition to increasing the packet size, one wants to reduce the interval between packets quite a lot. Some ping implementations have a “flood” mode which can also be useful.

Comment: @Chester Gillon Thanks for the answers, but for now what I'm interested in validating is only the hardware part on my board, everything that concerns the software or the hardware inside the MCU doesn't interest me for now, because the software will be written later and only after it is written will it be validated, while as regards the MCU hardware I can't do anything about it.